# Is there a standard attribute for the names of the dimensions of an array? (eg 3D array -> 3 names)

Tags: r, arrays, attributes

*[Edit: I think R itself suggests the answer; see below.]*

Suppose I have a 3D array such as

```
myarray <- array(1:8, dim=c(2,2,2), dimnames=list(letters[1:2], letters[3:4], letters[5:6]))
myarray
## , , e
##   c d
## a 1 3
## b 2 4
##
## , , f
##   c d
## a 5 7
## b 6 8
```

I would like to **name its three dimensions**, for example `'X'`, `'Y'`, `'Z'`. Note the difference with naming the *values of each dimension*, which is what `dimnames` already does.

I suppose I could either just add a custom attribute, eg `dimensions`:

```
attr(myarray, 'dimensions') <- c('X','Y','Z')

str(myarray)
## int [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
## - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
##  ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
##  ..$ : chr [1:2] "c" "d"
##  ..$ : chr [1:2] "e" "f"
## - attr(*, "dimensions")= chr [1:3] "X" "Y" "Z"
```

or I could name the existing `dimnames` attribute:

```
names(dimnames(myarray)) <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')

str(myarray)
## int [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
## - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
##  ..$ X: chr [1:2] "a" "b"
##  ..$ Y: chr [1:2] "c" "d"
##  ..$ Z: chr [1:2] "e" "f"
```

My question is: Is there a standard R attribute already designed for this? Or, if not, do you see any advantage in either approach above over the other? Or can think of a better approach? Cheers!

*Edit:* As an example application, one might want to use `apply` on some of the dimensions of the array, and having character names may provide for a user-friendlier interface. For instance, `myarray` could be an array of frequencies over three variates `'X'`, `'Y'`, `'Z'`. One might want the array of marginal frequencies for the variates `'X'`, `'Z'`, marginalizing out `'Y'`:

```
indices <- match(c('X','Z'), names(dimnames(myarray)))

apply(myarray, indices, sum)
##    Z
## X   e  f
##   a 4 12
##   b 6 14
```

*Edit 2:* The help of `apply` says, about the `MARGIN` argument:

> Where X has named dimnames, it can be a character vector selecting dimension names.

So it looks like `names(dimnames(...)) <- ...` is the way to go!

Comment: `array(1:8, dim=c(2,2,2), dimnames=list(x = letters[1:2], y = letters[3:4], z = letters[5:6]))`

Comment: @rawr great, even better, cheers!

Comment: programmatically i would prefer the `names(dimnames(...)) <- ...` version

Comment: @pglpm great that you found some solutions - its better practice on SO to [post the solution as an answer yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406950/answer-own-question) as opposed to edit your question. This will help others in the future. Glad you got what you needed!

Comment: @jpsmith Completely agree, I just wanted to wait a little in case someone wrote a more complete and informative solution, maybe mentioning other aspects of R I didin't know about :)

Answer (score 0):

The question gives an example application of naming the dimensions of an array: a more user-friendly specification of the dimensions on which `apply` should be applied. Well it turns out that `apply` already has you covered. From its [help pages](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/apply.html):

> apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE)
>
> Arguments
> [...]
>
> MARGIN
>
> a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns. ***Where X has named dimnames, it can be a character vector selecting dimension names.***

As the emphasized text says, `apply` already accounts for the possibility that the `dimnames()` elements of an array have names – that is, names for the dimensions.

So it looks like the standard way to specify names for the dimensions of an array is as names of its `dimnames` attribute.

This can be done (1) as the array is built, e.g.

```
myarray <- array(1:(2*3*4), dim=c(2,3,4),
                 dimnames=list(X = letters[1:2],
                               Y = letters[1:3],
                               Z = letters[1:4]))
```

where the dimensions' names are `'X'`, `'Y'`, `'Z'`; or (2) afterwards with

```
names(dimnames(myarray)) <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

which, as commented by @rawr, can be preferable programmatically.